# Singleemailmethod with BCC and Template ID

Tags: apex, batch, visualforce-component, massemailmessage, singleemailmessage

I am using a batch class with 4 differnt VF templates to send emails to 4 different regional heads using`singleemailmethod()` so I am using 4/10 singleemail methods in the batch class.

singleemail supports `settargetId()` and not `settargetIds()` as massemail, which makes it hard to specify multiple Id's too :(

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

singleemailmethod does not support `setbcc,setcc etc...` when used with a `templateID`, so I thought i would look into `massemailmessage`() but the problem there is It does not support Vf templates.

```
INVALID_ID_FIELD, Visualforce templates are not currently supported for mass email.: []
```

I cannot use what Id too here because I have 4 different templates which needs to be used based on region,making it hard to run all this in a for loop.

Am I doing something totally off that can be corrected,**I want to cc/bcc the email templates to some admin users who will get copy of all the emails that is being sent over from this class.How do I copy a template to multiple users?**

code:

```
global class Schedule_report implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)
    {
        list<EmailTemplate> lstEmailTemplates = [select Id,Name,DeveloperName from EmailTemplate where( Name=: 'NA' OR Name=: 'ASIA_Pacific' OR Name=: 'Europe' OR Name=: 'Japan')];

        map<string,string> emailmap = new map<string,string>();
        if(lstEmailTemplates!=null && lstEmailTemplates.size()>0)
        {
            for(emailtemplate e: lstEmailTemplates){
            emailmap.put(e.name,e.id);
            }
        }

        if(emailmap.containsKey('NA')){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTargetObjectId('005d0000001TT4P');
                mail.setTemplateId(emailmap.get('NA'));
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultMail = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
       }
        if(emailmap.containsKey('ASIA_Pacific')){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTargetObjectId('005d0000001TT4Q');
                mail.setTemplateId(emailmap.get('ASIA_Pacific'));
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultMail = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
       }
        if(emailmap.containsKey('Europe')){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTargetObjectId('005d0000001TT4R');
                mail.setTemplateId(emailmap.get('Europe'));
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultMail = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
       }

       if(emailmap.containsKey('Japan')){
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTargetObjectId('005d0000001TT4S');
                mail.setTemplateId(emailmap.get('Japan'));
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultMail = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can only call sendEmail 10 times in a context. But each call can contain multiple messages. You have it coded to only use a single entry in the list for each send
So where you have

```
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultMail = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

You could have something like

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for (// blah blah loop stuff
    mailsToSend.add(mail);
}
// and then 
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] resultMail = Messaging.sendEmail(mailsToSend);
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.Was one of those days where my brain froze and never had any juice left to think :)